# Opening TIFF DEMs in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, aster

I have files, in Tiff format, downloaded from ASTER-GDEM.

Can I open this file with QGIS? If yes, how?

Answer (score 29):

From your question, I'm assuming you are a new user of [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org).
`Tiff` files are a type of [Raster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics), which are supported in QGIS.  The fact that your Tiff is a [DEM (Digital Elevation Model)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_elevation_model) just gives meaning to the values of the pixels in the Raster, but does not affect the file format.

That all being said.  Here is how to add a Raster (Tiff, in your case) in 2 easy steps.

1. **Click on `Add Raster Layer`**
   [image: Add Raster Layer]
2. **Select the `.tiff` file**, and press `Open`
   [image: Select .tiff file]

Here is the result:
[image]

Since your raster is a DEM, there are a couple additional steps necessary to make it display properly.

1. **Right click** on the image in the Table of Contents and **Select** `Properties`
   [image: Select Layer Properties]
2. **Select** the `Style Tab` and under **Contrast enhancement**, **Change** the **Current** pulldown from *Default* `No Stretch`, to `Stretch to MinMax`
   [image: Change Style property]

Here is the end result with the DEM symbolized based on the raster values.
[image: Raster DEM Symbology]

This process all being said and done, I would strongly recommend you to peruse the latest QGIS documentation:  [Version 1.8](http://docs.qgis.org/user_guide/html/en/)
As well, there is a wiki for QGIS that may be most helpful:  [How do I do that in QGIS?](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/How_do_I_do_that_in_QGIS)

It is likely that these two resources may lead you to an answer, as well as provide you with additional information.

Good luck!